# Is it possible to change SharePoint 2013 Web Services port for service application web services?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, service-application

I'm trying to satisfy [DoD STIG ID IISW-SI-000219](https://vaulted.io/library/disa-stigs-srgs/iis_85_site_security_technical_implementation_guide/IISW-SI-000219?version=v1r0.1) which states that all web sites must be bound in site bindings to an assigned IP and an assigned host name and that those sites using HTTP must use port 80, while those using HTTPS must use port 443.  So, this is my question: Since SharePoint's service application's web services run as a separate web site, and as such, must also abide by this rule, how can I make these web services run under port 443?  I've already changed their host name and IP which worked, but they still run under the standard 32845 port (for HTTPS - I removed the HTTP binding, per another regulation).

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Server.

Does any one know how to change the port number of the service application web services?  Is it even possible?

The fact of whether it is a good idea is NOT relevant here.  I can't change the requirement given to me.

Thanks for reading.

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint has it's own specific STiG to follow. But no, that port is required. You cannot follow the IIS STiG, just like SharePoint has considerations that prevent you from following the Windows STiG.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Trevor.  Do you have any Microsoft documentation I can provide to back the case that the ports can't be altered?

Comment: Ah sorry, what I said is _not_ true. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/security-hardening#ServiceApp.

Comment: I'm happy for the knowledge.  This helps me tremulously.  Many thanks

Comment: as far as i know THOSE PORTS SHOULD NEVER BE CHANGED... PERIOD !